# Master-Slave DNS Ubuntu Configuration on AWS

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, bind

I have following architecture.

Domain example.com registered with external provider.

2 DNS to-be servers within AWS:

> DNS SERVER 1 (MASTER):
>
> Public IP: 100.200.300.400 | Public DNS: 100-200-300-400.aws.com |
>   Private IP: 1.2.3.4
>
> DNS SERVER 2 (SLAVE):
>
> Public IP: 101.202.303.404 | Public DNS: 101-202-303-404.aws.com |
>   Private IP: 5.6.7.8

**named.conf.local**

MASTER:

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
        notify yes;
        allow-transfer { 5.6.7.8; };
};
```

SLAVE:

```
zone "example.com" {
        type slave;
        file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
        notify yes;
        allow-transfer { 1.2.3.4; };
};
```

And **db.example.com**

```
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     localhost root.localhost. (
                        1               ; Serial
                        15M             ; Refresh
                        15M             ; Retry
                        15M             ; Expire
                        15M )           ; Negative Cache TTL
;
example.com.     IN      A       SOME-IP
```

My questions: is this configuration OK?

In particulary I wonder:

*should I use private or public ip to communicate master-slave

*is localhost root.localhost. in **db.example.com** proper?

Answer (score 0):

I configured Master - Slave DNS server with Ubuntu in AWS. Configure Public IP ( Elastic IP ) for these two instances. Put FQDN on each server resolving to the elastic IP. Instead of localhost use fqdn. I followed Ubuntu HOWTO for this implementation.

Use "also-notify" statement in Slave server. Change localhost with FQDN in all configuration files. Rest of the syntax seems ok.

Before DNS configuration, make sure each server resolving its own public IP and resolving corresponding IPs from other server.

Comment: how to "make sure each server resolving its own public IP"?

ping on localhost on DNS server?
ping on EIP?

Comment: Ping Server A fqdn from Server A resolve to its own elastic IP. Ping Server B fqdn from Server B resolves to its own elastic IP. Ping ServerB fqdn from Server A resolves to Server B elastic IP and vise versa.

Comment: ... and dont forget to open 53 TCP/UDP port which was my issue